# Reduce Seaborn KDE Plot Margins

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, seaborn

Hi I have code below that produces multiple KDE plot on the margins of a jointplot

```
h = sns.JointGrid('SECS', 'EPOCH', df)

for name, group in df.groupby("QUERY"):
    sns.kdeplot(group["SECS"], ax=h.ax_marg_x, legend=False)
    sns.kdeplot(group["EPOCH"], ax=h.ax_marg_y, vertical=True, legend=False)
    h.ax_joint.plot(group["SECS"], group["EPOCH"], ".", ms=5)
```

[image]

I'd be interested to know how to limit the margins so that the graph starts from 0 and not from -20000, there's lot of dead space there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the main plot of a `JointGrid` using `ax_joint` as you have done to plot the data in the first place. If you print the type of `h.ax_joint` you can see it is a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`. Therefore you can manipulate the limits of the axes as you normally would with matplotlib.

For example:

```
h = sns.JointGrid('SECS', 'EPOCH', df)

for name, group in df.groupby("QUERY"):
    sns.kdeplot(group["SECS"], ax=h.ax_marg_x, legend=False)
    sns.kdeplot(group["EPOCH"], ax=h.ax_marg_y, vertical=True, legend=False)
    h.ax_joint.plot(group["SECS"], group["EPOCH"], ".", ms=5)

h.ax_joint.set_xlim(0,90000)
```